# Android 12 having android.app.ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException issue

Tags: android

**I have defined target SDK Version 30. I only get this error on Android 12 devices.
How can I fix this issue?**

```
android.app.ForegroundServiceDidNotStartInTimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException (ActivityThread.java:2143)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900 (ActivityThread.java:310)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2372)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)enter code here
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:567)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Comment: [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#background-start-restrictions) maybe this could help.